# How to correct upside-down label in LeaderLine?

Tags: javascript

I am using [`LeaderLine`](https://anseki.github.io/leader-line/) and want to draw a line with a label between an `input` and a `button`. The `button` is to the right of the `input`.

Currently the label is upside down, I want it to be right-side up. I can't find any way to rotate or flip the text in the documentation and I don't want to change the positions of either element.

How can I make it so the text on the line is no longer upside down?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leader-line@1.0.5/leader-line.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            new LeaderLine(
                document.getElementById("btn"),
                document.getElementById("text"),
                {color: "red", size: 8, startLabel: LeaderLine.pathLabel("This is a label")}
            );
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="text">Text: </label>
<input id="text" type="text">
<button id="btn" type="button" style="margin-left:500px;">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the `pathLabel` with `captionLabel`. https://anseki.github.io/leader-line/#captionlabel

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leader-line@1.0.5/leader-line.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            new LeaderLine(
                document.getElementById("btn"),
                document.getElementById("text"),
                {color: "red", size: 8, startLabel: LeaderLine.captionLabel("This is a label")}
            );
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="text">Text: </label>
<input id="text" type="text">
<button id="btn" type="button" style="margin-left:500px;">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is to swap the start and end, set `startPlug` to `"arrow1"` (or any other plug you want to use) and `endPlug` to `"behind"`.

This way it is possible to keep the effect where the text curves along with the path. It is however less intuitive than just using `captionLabel` as in Nicolae Maties solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leader-line@1.0.5/leader-line.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            new LeaderLine(
                document.getElementById("text"),  // start and end were switched
                document.getElementById("btn"),
                {color: "red", size: 8, endLabel: LeaderLine.pathLabel("This is a label"), startPlug: "arrow1", endPlug: "behind"}
            );
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="text">Text: </label>
<input id="text" type="text">
<button id="btn" type="button" style="margin-left:500px;">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```